# Ethernet without cables

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, tv

I have a Wi-Fi router and is going to buy a TV. Our Internet provider also offers TV service, it gives for free a special receiver, which is connected with Ethernet and HDMI cables to the router and TV respectively. However, it's not very convenient for me to put the Ethernet cable between the router and receiver. Are there some devices (preferably small and cheap, of course) which can serve as a bridge between Wi-Fi and Ethernet in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You coudld use a [WiFi extender](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&q=wifi+extender&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=1061062019541579376&sa=X&ei=ch4EUP_MNsLIhAeo4diKCA&ved=0CG0Q8wIwAQ). This allows it to join your current network and then take a Ethernet out.

Comment: It seems that it's the device I need)) I've even found it in a shop nearby. But according to its description at Google, it acts like an additional access point, while I need to connect an Ethernet device to existing Wi-Fi network...

Comment: An additional access point is connecting you to your existing WIFI network.  It should be completely transparent to the device you connect using the builtin Ethernet ports.

Comment: @chersanya You can also configure it so you plug an ethernet cord into your tuner box, other end to the repeater and have it get access

Comment: Think the guy above have explained all. But Yes is correct the additional access point would be your current network.

Comment: So as I understood, it's possible to configure this Wi-Fi extender to be a bridge between Wi-Fi network and an Ethernet device, which otherwise would be connected to the same network using a cable. But how to do such configuration? I haven't seen such options at any router, or this extender is special?

Comment: Basically, The router uses WDS, It connects to your previous Wireless network, then extends it over WiFi and Ethernet.These are WiFi Extenders not routers. Some expensive routers have WDS built in however.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a powerline ethernet adapter and use your existing electrical wiring for ethernet networking. There are many brands and models to choose from, many of them relatively inexpensive.

Here's a [sampling](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss/186-6963650-1311336?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=Powerline+Ethernet) from Amazon.com.